# creating mysql update stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

am getting error 1064 creating an update stored procedure, i dont know where am wrong

```
DELIMITER $$
```

CREATE

```
PROCEDURE `sms_pigen`.`sp_update`(IN Clearing_Agent_ID INT(11), IN ClientCode VARCHAR(10), IN ClientName VARCHAR(50), IN PostalAdd VARCHAR(200), IN Telephone VARCHAR(30), IN Fax VARCHAR (30), IN EmailAdd1 VARCHAR(255), IN EmailAdd2 VARCHAR(255), IN EmailAdd3 VARCHAR(255), IN Website VARCHAR(50), IN TotalDeposit DECIMAL(18,2), IN AccountBal DECIMAL(18,2), IN ChargeRate DECIMAL(10,2))

BEGIN
UPDATE t_pi_clients SET pClientCode = ClientCode, pClientName = ClientName, pPostalAdd = PostalAdd, pTelephone = Telephone, pFax = Fax, pEmailAdd1 = EmailAdd1, pEmailAdd2 = EmailAdd2, pEmailAdd3 = EmailAdd3, pWebsite = Website, pTotalDeposit = TotalDeposit, pAccountBal = AccountBal, pChargeRate = ChargeRate WHERE Clearing_Agent_ID = Clearing_Agent_ID;

END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

Error code

```
Query : CREATE     /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/     PROCEDURE `sms_pigen`.`sp_update`(IN Clearing_Agent_ID INT(11), IN Client...
```

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/*LANGUAGE SQL
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    END$$
DELIMITER' at line 16
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Comment: What are you using to run this create code as it looks like it is injecting some extra text?

Comment: looks like my end$$ was somehow commented,so problem solved ty

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`pcbb-uat`@`%` PROCEDURE `Update_Data`(IN TABLE_NAME longtext,in column_name varchar(1000),in column_value longtext,in Parameter varchar(1000),in parameter_value varchar(100))
BEGIN
     
                set @whereclouse = CONCAT('[',Parameter,'] = ''',parameter_value,'''');
                SET @query = CONCAT('update [',TABLE_NAME,'] SET [',column_name,'] = ''',column_value,'''  WHERE ');
                set @updt = concat(@query,@whereclouse);
                select @updt;
                PREPARE stmt FROM @updt;
                EXECUTE stmt ;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: please provide description to your answer, in this way maybe some people couldnt find what was wrong.